# Why are cross-posted questions deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

If a question is posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites, why are they deleted by moderators?

If they are unable to answer, why don't they leave them as-is? There are many experts who participate on one Stack Exchange site but not on others, so an answer may come from any site. After getting a few good comments, I could not even reply to the users asking how it's done.

I thought Stack Exchange was about solving problems people are facing by sharing them with other users who might know the answer and can help. Moderators are just showing their power without answering. If you can, just help the person, instead of pulling the leg of a beginner.

Comment: Crossposting on multiple sites is abusive behavior. Also -1 for "Moderators showing their power". Look at our contribs first before the Moderator power overload meme

Comment: @Sathya i'm having trouble with a problem for so many years. posted the problem though didn't know where to post and comments guide me to post in the appropriate site, i got a good comment regarding the problem. i can't even reply to him asking some details. just because a moderator deleted the question. if i'd know all the rules and regulations and would be a pro, i'd be a moderator, not a beginner. and i'd not even bother asking questions rather i'd be solving them.

Comment: @Sathya i didn't meant to hurt all the moderators with my words for the work of a single moderator. sorry for that. but when a person is in problem, a moderator will push him to another problem deleting his question rather than solving it. how'd the person feel?

Comment: I can't see how the same question would even be on-topic for multiple Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Just so you know, moderators don't necessarily have anything to do with this. Have a look [here](http://www.superuser.com/privileges), any user with enough rep can vote to close or delete a question.

Answer (score 11):

You've posted [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/709548/installing-linux-kernel-in-uefi-with-h2o-inside-bios) across 3 sites in the Stack Exchange network.

You're reasoning for that was, that you didn't get good "view rates". If you feel like not enough people have viewed your question within the first hour, then that is no reason to post the same question on another site, for several reasons:

1. 1 hour is an insignificant amount given the lifetime of a question. If your question is relevant and interesting it will be viewed many times in the future. **Never** expect to get the answer you're looking for within the first day.
2. It doesn't matter how *many* people viewed your question. In the end, you only care about that 1 person that posts the answer you're looking for.
3. You **never** post the same question on multiple sites in the Stack Exchange network. There are many questions across the meta sites of the network that handle this topic. To get you started, read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Long story short, we don't want the same question on multiple sites. Multiple people might invest their time and then, in the end, create duplicate information. We hate duplicate information.

So, that's why your question was deleted, not because we "were unable to answer" or "want to show our power". Quite honestly, those allegations are offensive and not the proper way to start a discussion about the reasoning about the way your post was handled.

For the future, if you feel like you've been unfairly dealt with, post on meta, but bring up the problem without accusing people of having negative character traits.
If you have a question on a site for several days and it has not gained any attention, you can flag that question and ask for it to be migrated to another site; which is the proper way of dealing with a situation like this.

Comment: thanks for responding. i said sorry for my rude behaviour. but before deleting, they should see the response the questions have got. after the deletion, we've no way to contact a person who've posted a valued comment. and already said, i'm new here. don't know many of the options, what they do. and i also mentioned why i posted in 3 sites. still sorry for everything.

Comment: @RatDon If the question had received an *actual* response in form of an answer, it would not have been deleted, but migrated to the other site and then merged into one. But for a question without answers, this is usually too much effort, since it also involves contacting moderators on the other site and manually merging questions. You don't have to excuse yourself for not knowing about the policy—everybody starts out here at some point.

Comment: @slhck okay thanks.. may be if the question would not be deleted, i'd not be knowing this policy of stack exchange. yeah everybody starts out at some point. and i understand my mistake after knowing the trouble moderators have to go through.